# Galeria no muestra foto tomada con la camara app Android Studio

Tags: java, android

**manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Consultartlista"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Agregarpersonaje" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>

</application>
```

**Activity:**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Consultartlista.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Consultartlista.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Consultartlista.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1000);
        }        

String currentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

private void tomarFoto() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
          Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}


    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.agregarimg:
            tomarFoto();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

    }

}

    @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater2 = getMenuInflater();
    inflater2.inflate(R.menu.menuopcionesimg,menu);

}
```

y aca les dejo una ss del pathfiles porque no me deja pegarlo aca, no se porque

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKwhJ.png

Mi app, es una base de datos simple, (estoy aprendiendo) y tengo una listview que muestra los datos, cuando hago un shortclick en un item, se abre un menu contextual con opción de "agregar imagen", el cual abre la camara, y toma foto, tuve problemas con los API's. Muy bien no se como va el tema, pero cambie al api 28 (Android Pie) recien ahi, las fotos se guardaron en la sdcard, antes cuando compilaba con API 29 no se guardaban. Bueno, al usar API 28, se guardan las fotos en la sdcard lo confirmo mirando los archivos del celular, pero no aparecen en la galeria, tengo que reiniciar el celular (Samsung j7 android pie 9) para que la galeria muestre las fotos que saque atraves de mi app, como podria solucionar eso?

Comment: Revisa si existe un error en el LogCat, es super importante el uso del LogCat  cuando desarrollas en Android.

Comment: @Jorgesys Hola, no tengo nada en el LogCat, tampoco en la pestaña de errores y warn del log cat, lo q hice hace poco fue probar la misma app pero en android 4.4.4 y funciona lo mas bien, la foto se agrega a la galeria sin problema. El tema es con android 9, yo ahi, descargue una galeria de la store y la seguia sin mostrar, pero vi q tenia una opcion de "mostrar ocultos" aprete, y ahi me salia el album de mi app como (oculto), porque? como podria solucionar eos para que funcione bien en android pie 9?

Comment: Para guardar imágenes en Android hay dos maneras, antes de AndroidQ y AndroidQ y superior.  En este caso, entiendo que estás destinado a AndroidQ+ porque tu path es Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, en este caso, no necesitas ni crearte un fichero temporal, puedes guardar el bitmap directamente.  Para esto mira cómo hacerlo con ContentResolver para crear la URI, y después con el método openOutputStream(uri).